# Find all integer-valued functions f(n) taking values in the integers satisfying the equation f[f(n)]=n+1

Tags: functional-equations

I tried taking both sides f which doesn't gave the solution

My work

=> f(f(n))=n+1
=> Taking both sides f

=> f(f(f(n))) = f(n+1)

=> f(n+1)= f(n+1)

I am stucked here

Comment: If you substitute $n$ with $f(n)$, you get $f(f(f(n))) = f(n) + 1$. You also showed that $f(f(f(n))) = f(n+1)$. So, $f(n+1) = f(n) + 1$. Continue from here.